# Convert geographic coordinates into svg coordinates

Tags: svg, rendering, geospatial, openstreetmap, geo

I want to build a Node JS application that generates an SVG image from geographic coordinates it fetches from [overpass](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

I tried to implement that by just using the geographic coordinates as coordinates for SVG paths, but the result looks distorted (it should look like [this](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/TMf)):

[image]

I assume the problem is that the earth is actually a sphere and there needs to be done some math in order to get a correct map projection.

What is the actual problem here? Are there any existing algorithms or libraries to cope with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The math behind this is called [map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection).

Many online maps use the [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). The [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator) has example code in various languages. I'm sure you will find more libraries on the Internet.